# How do I write and read data in txt file in the form of rows and columns?

Tags: java, file-io

How do I write and read data in txt file in the form of rows and columns?  Also, how do I store many files like this in a folder for a particular name? The idea is just like a Table for a particular person who has many rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Jeremy's post

1. Use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to create the csv file
2. Use [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) to use JDBC to query against those files. This makes the future transition to DB in future and you will be working with a known API for searching against the file

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into [comma-separated value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files.